# Failed to Parse error on running lookup (aggregate) - using mongodb atlas

Tags: node.js, api, express, mongodb-atlas

[image: code of the controller used]
[image: postman error]

it is working on local database but not working on atlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lookup has typo,

```
$lookup: {
  form: <<-- this needs to be "from"
}
```